# STL sorted vector find first element less than or equal to given value

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, binary-search

I have a vector of `pairs`. Suppose it is like this:

```
vector<pair<int,int>> vec = { {1,12}, {1,5}, {1,6}, {1,9}, {3,9}, {3,11}, {3,13}, {3,4}, {5,9}, {5,91}, {13,8}, {16,8}, {20,8}, {20,81} };
```

The `pairs` are sorted by first element.

Given a `pair`, I need to find the index of the last `pair` in the vector whose first element is less than or equal to first element of the given pair. If for that last `pair`, other pairs lie to its left with the same value of the first element, I need the first of all those pairs:

```
<4,10> => 4 (vec[4] is <3,9>, the elements with the largest first value less than or equal to 4 are those with first element as 3, and there are 4 pairs with a 3 in the first element, at indices 4-7, so return the first of those pairs)

<0,10> => -1, since no element exists to its right.

<1,6> => 0 (vec[0] is <1,12>. There is no pair whose first element is less than 1, and there are 4 pairs, including <1,6> whose first element is 1. So we need the first of these 4 pairs.)

<23,81> => 12 (vec[12] is <20,8>)
```

Condition: I need to use only standard algorithms like `upper_bound`, `binary_search` and `lower_bound`. I tried this, but it is failing badly:

```
vector<pair<int,int>> vec = { {1,12}, {1,5}, {1,6},{1,9}, {3,9}, {3,11}, {3,13}, {3,4}, {5,9}, {5,91}, {13,8}, {16,8}, {20,8}, {20,81} };

auto i = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), make_pair<int,int>(4,10),
    [](const pair<int,int>& f1, const pair<int,int>& f2) { return f1.first < f2.first; });

cout << i-vec.begin();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want the **first pair**, you maybe want to combine lower and upper bound?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair <int,int> > vec = { {1,12}, {1,5}, {1,6}, {1,9}, {3,9}, {3,11}, {3,13}, {3,4}, {5,9}, {5,91}, {13,8}, {16,8}, {20,8}, {20,81} };

    auto u_it = std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), make_pair<int,int>(4, 10),
        [](const pair<int,int>& f1, const pair<int,int>& f2) { return f1.first < f2.first; });

    if(u_it == vec.begin())
        cout << "-1\n";

    auto l_it = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), u_it, *prev(u_it),
        [](const pair<int,int>& f1, const pair<int,int>& f2) { return f1.first < f2.first; });

    cout << l_it - vec.begin() << "\n";
    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall -std=c++0x main.cpp 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
4
```

PS -  answer updated after WhozCraig's comment:

> you want to use `it = std::upper_bound(beg,end)` to find the first strictly-greater element, and if that answers non-begin, then use `std::lower_bound(beg,it)` to find the lowest-matching ordinal of the element whose value is pulled from `(it-1)`.

The answer now *satisfies all* the *test cases* you have provided (I am not showing it here). Hope that helps! :)

---

Appendix:

Ref for [std::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/), [std::upper_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) and [std::prev](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/prev/). Please notice how the `std::lower_bound` call uses `std::make_pair` *without* an initializing list, so that it lets the compiler come into play and resolve [deduce the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358240/weird-compiler-error-cannot-convert-parameter-from-int-to-int).

Comment: `(4 - 1,10)` ? What is that?

Comment: @SexyBeast I updated the answer, hope now everything is clear!

Comment: This is a terrific answer! Thanks buddy! I will give it a bounty in some time! While you are at it, the vector initialization code has been cropped off with a dollar sign!

Comment: @SexyBeast good it helped! Well to be honest I was about to drop off and feel good for answer [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748090/generating-random-number-on-set-interval-in-c/40748148#40748148). It was only for you and WhozCraig's comments to get back into the game! Just accept the answer, no need to give away your rep, I already answered! :) You may needed for desperate times when a question that you die to find an answer is left unanswered after a while... ;)

Comment: Off topic question, instead of using `make_pair` in the comparator function, can't I just use an int, like 4 here to represent the first value only, since the second value is redundant, and use that in the function somehow?

Comment: There must be a way and I was thinking of the very same thing to be honest! However, it's not as simple as just changing the comparator functions and the `val` of the bounds. We are passing a vector of pairs as input, which complicates things @SexyBeast. maybe it would be sane to post a new question, linking to this one and my answer, asking how to!

Comment: That's a reasonable halfway solution @SexyBeast, I agree! ;)

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Comment: Umm, no, I just added a `{0,1}` at the beginning and searched for it, I am getting `0`.

Comment: @SexyBeast well danged if it does! My mistake, I'll delete my comment. P.S. Why `make_pair(prev(u_it)->first, 10)` instead of just `*prev(u_it)`?

Comment: SexyBeast is right, the code works for that case too! Just checked! @MarkRansom I was having some compiler issues and overkilled it, updated, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

`std::lower_bound` returns the **first** item **greater or equal to** the given value

---

you need to

- `+1` to the input of `std::lower_bound`
- `-1` to the result of `std::lower_bound`

to find the value (or you can use `std::upper_bound`)

and use `std::lower_bound` again to find the right pair

---

example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int my_find(const vector<pair<int,int>>& vec, int value){
   auto comparer = [](const pair<int,int>& f1, int value) { return f1.first < value; };

   auto i = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value+1, comparer);
   if(i==vec.begin()){return -1;}

   i = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), (i-1)->first, comparer);
   return i-vec.begin();
}

int main(){

   vector<pair<int,int>> vec = { {1,12}, {1,5}, {1,6},{1,9}, {3,9}, {3,11}, {3,13}, {3,4}, {5,9}, {5,91}, {13,8}, {16,8}, {20,8}, {20,81} };

   cout << my_find(vec,-1) << '\n';
   cout << my_find(vec,3) << '\n';
   cout << my_find(vec,10) << '\n';
   cout << my_find(vec,100) << '\n';
}
```

---

BTW, you don't need to provide `pair` to `lower_bound`

and if you only use `lower_bound`, you need only one comparer

Comment: And since we are looking for the *last* item, we should use `std::upper_bound()` and check if `it-1` is even valid.

Comment: Can you give me a working example, with the comparator function? I am having a bit of difficulty in visualizing this.. :(

Comment: @SexyBeast I suppose you `make_pair<int,int>(4,10)` because you need to find last element of `3` BTW

Comment: Subtracting 1 from `i` does not work, gives me wrong results. I get `7`, which is the index of the last `3`, whereas I want `4`, the index of the first `3`.

Comment: @SexyBeast it looks [pretty good](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jvtJbWupEHxgB0AJ) to me

Comment: First, `lower_bound` returns the first *greater than or equal*, not greater than. Second, subtracting one from an iterator without first checking to see if it's equal to `begin()` is an error.

Comment: @MarkRansom so I `+1` to it's input, do you look at my [previous working example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jvtJbWupEHxgB0AJ)? For the equal to `begin()` it will only equal to `begin()` if the set is empty. and is not the core of this solution.

Comment: @appleapple, please find that in the next line I wrote **If for that last pair, other pairs lie to its left with the same value of the first element, I need the first of all those pairs**.

Comment: Which doesn't apply to the test case for `<1,6>` you provided.

Comment: @SimonKraemer it returns `3(<1,9>)` which is right, are you get different result? [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XUpKuvBFur1eIr5Q)

Comment: Edited my question, sorry for a mistake, for `<1,6>` the answer would be `0` and not `1`.

Comment: @appleapple As far as I understand the question it shoudl return `2` for the elements `<1,12>` and `<1,5>` which both lie left to the first value greater or equal to `<1,6>` (which is `<1,6>`) and have the same value in the first part (which is `1`)

Comment: @SimonKraemer Answer updated, is this what you want?

Comment: @MarkRansom sorry, you are right, I was confused by the two, answer updated, thankyou.

Comment: The answer is accurate now, whoever downvoted this, please upvote it now. This required lot of hard work.